# Can I use my keyboard for touch instead of my mouse on android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, google-play-games

I would like to be able to use my hardware keyboard (on my M1 MacBook) within games (such as stumble guys) on android studio.

I use a Pixel 4 API 31 (ARM 64) on android 12.0.

The keyboard works for typing functions where the onscreen keyboard would be required.

However I am wondering how I can use my keyboard to emulate touch instead of having to use my mouse. Can I assign keys to areas on the phone ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The feature you request would have to be built into the emulator - translating keyboard input to touch inptu before it hits the target Android software. Since you're saying "on android studio" I'm assuming you refer to the AVD Android Studio Emulator. I am pretty sure that emulator does not support the feature you request, nor have I heard of any other that supports it.